# How to render custom form in active admin dashboard - Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, formtastic

I want to render custom form in active admin dashboard page. Code looks like:

**apps/views/admin/dashboard/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= semantic_form_for :bill, builder: ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder,action:"new" do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :from_date%>
        <%= f.input :to_date%>
        <%= f.input :expiry_date%>
        <%=f.actions :submit %>
<%end%>
```

**app/admin/dashboard.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Dashboard" do

  menu priority: 1, label: proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") }

  content title: proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") } do

 columns do
   column do
     panel "Generate Bills" do
        render partial: 'form'
     end
   end
   column do
     panel "Pay Bills" do

     end
   end

 end
  end
end
```

I want **new method** of bill **resource** to be run on this form, because I want the active admin user to create bill objects from **dashboard**!

Answer (score 0):

For rendering partial form in active admin

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Dashboard" do

  menu priority: 1, label: proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") }

  content title: proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") } do

 columns do
   column do
     panel "Generate Bills" do
        form :partial => "form"
     end
   end
   column do
     panel "Pay Bills" do

     end
   end

 end
  end
end
```

Comment: For me, this renders `<form partial="form"></form>`

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a form in in this location: 
   `app/views/admin/dashboard/_my_cool_form.html.erb`
2. In your `app/admin/dashboard.rb` file: Call your form as. 
   `render partial: "my_cool_form`

That's it.